# Browse SD card on android button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sdcard

I have the following code for browsing Gallery on button click.

```
loadFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
   }
});
```

Instead I need to access SD Card on button click.
I have edited the code to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

I got error. I am new to android. How can I do it? Please help me.

Comment: So what is the problem? Your code shows that you have implemented on button click.

Comment: Its showing gallery. Instead I need Storage(SD card).

Comment: do you want to open a particular location or just browse from a parent dir

@PiyushGupta think he needs to open a location or browse sdcard instead of gallery.

Comment: @user2450263 Yes he is.

Comment: @user3377887 Then fetch images from file using getExternalDirectiory() function.

Comment: I need to open the location and have capable of selecting file  from that location. I hope you understand my concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
```

You should change this

```
String myFilepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

File f = new File(myFilepath);
```

Add permission to your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: On click I should able to browse the location of SD card

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
 final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
 private String selectedImage;

 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                selectedImage = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
                yourImageView.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImage));
            }  else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            }
        }

}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
}

public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;

            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

See details on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html